# Neo4j import postgres data from VM

Tags: postgresql, neo4j, etl

I'm trying to import a Postgres database from a VM, and use Neo4j to visualize the graph.
For a sample of such a database, I am able to load the data using ETL tools and run it on my local Windows machine using Neo4j desktop.

However, when I try to load the database from VM (Centos), I can not load it from ETL. It gives me this error:

```
Connection failed. SQL state: 08001, message: Connection to localhost:7687 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
close
```

[image]

And on my VM, my Neo4j status looks like this:
[image]

Am I doing correctly? Or I should not use ETL tool for loading external database in the beginning? What is the best approach in my case?

Please advise and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `username` and `password` appropriate for logging into the neo4j server.